# In camel 2.22.x how can I force SEDA to have an unlimited queue size?

Tags: apache-camel

I was trying to upgrade to Camel 2.22.1 but learned that there is a breaking change for me in the release of [2.22.0](http://camel.apache.org/camel-2220-release.html).

```
The SEDA component now has a default queue size of 1000 instead of unlimited.
```

This has not been documented in their [SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) API yet. How do I define the SEDA endpoint URL to have an unlimited queue again?

Comment: Better look at the asciidoc directly, since it has the latest version of the documentation https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/seda-component.adoc

Comment: Thanks - but they do not mention how to set the queue size to unlimited either :(

Comment: Yes they wanted to avoid out of memory errors as they state in the original ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12542 . I guess that after one point having no limit in the queue will lead to an OOME. Wouldn't it be OK if you just increased this limit to an appropriate for your application value?

Comment: I tried setting it to 100k and it was not yet enough. I can try with 1M but that is not a future proof approach. The reason is that the camel processor is traversing down an object tree and reinjecting subtasks into the same SEDA at the moment. If I set SEDA to be blocking I have a deadlock. So the best quick solution would be to keep it unlimited and let memory be my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I had a look at the source code of the file changes for [CAMEL-12525](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/apache/camel/-/commit/9e93427c2ad20ddd936dec56341891c7eb5b79b0)

I believe you can get the same kind of configuration if you configure the SEDA queue size to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` , as this used to be the Seda queue size limit before v2.22.0

Comment: how would that be written in an SEDA URL?

Comment: Can't be done in the URL.It has to be performed at component creation time. So it depends on the way you instantiate SedaComponent. In my case where I use camel&spring boot this could be done with just setting one property in my application.properties like camel.component.seda.queue-size=0x7fffffff .https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/d0e04616cebee03ecdd5ed5333ed57a93237b62c/platforms/spring-boot/components-starter/camel-core-starter/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/seda/springboot/SedaComponentConfiguration.java
Also have a look at http://camel.apache.org/componentconfiguration.html